# Migrate Flask API on AWS Lightsail to HTTPS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, https

I have an api running on a linux screen on an AWS lightsail instance. I use Flask to create the api, and it works great over http, but I need it to use https so that my website can access it since it autoblocks the request.

This is how I run the server:

```
# ./modules.trade_assistant.server.py

from flask import Flask, request, abort, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

# ... endpoints are here

def run_server(debug=False, port=7373):
    """Runs the server"""
    bind_address = '0.0.0.0:' + str(port)
    cmd = [
        'gunicorn', '-w', '4', '-b', bind_address,
        '--access-logfile', '-',  # Logs to stdout
        'modules.trade_assistant.server:app'
    ]
    
    #cmd.append('--log-level=warning')  # Optional: Adjust log level for production
    subprocess.run(cmd)
```

and then from the root directory I setup a linux screen and essentially just call run_server() from a python file in the root.

Any help on migrating this API to operate over HTTPS would be much appreciated!